# How to make Sequence Diagram for Update Inventory

Tags: uml, modeling, sequence-diagram

I'm preparing the sequence diagram for a project. I made the following sequence diagram for a retailer updating his inventory

It's confusing to me because this is the first time I use this technique with a real project.i have used database as an object here and i don't know whether its right or wrong. And another thing i need to clarify is by using Updating i meant for both editing/add new item To the inventory. Is it wrong to do like that way? or else can we draw it separately?

The following image is part of the updating process, would any one take a look and correct me if I did any mistake.(UpdateUI- User interface).Thanks in Advance.

[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look right. There are a couple of issues:

- Your database will likely never issue any messages
- Actions inside a DB are usually not exposed. You normally only call CRUD from outside for a DB.
- You mix synch/asynch (likely unwillingly). Filled arrows are synch, unfilled ones as asynch.
- Main Page is likely the V in MVC and UpdateUI the C. So the controller will act on a click from the user and interact with the DB.

So just from my guts here is a more reasonable sketch:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.  So user first click on update button on welcome page. Then is it wrong to show it as above and then via the database results are updated in updateUI ? and after getting results cant we show results at UI page with the help from database?

Comment: I tried to make an example from what I thought is your intention.

Comment: thank you very much thomas i am getting it. Hopefully i can do more when i draw more and more.

Comment: Yes, it need quite a bit of practice. Like any new language you learn.